# Should some of the "rewrite" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Some very similar tags:

- [rewrite](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite) × 28
- [mod-rewrite](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) × 239
- [url-rewriting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-rewriting) × 174

Comment: I think url-rewrite may be better since the wording rewrite is pretty broad standalone, while people searching for url or rewrite the tag will be found.

Comment: It turns out there is already a "url-rewriting" tag.  Should we merge "rewrite" into it?

Comment: The [url-rewriting](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-rewriting) wiki implies this tag references modifying the `appearance` of a URL (such as for search engine friendly URLs). The wiki for [rewrite](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/rewrite/info) references `transforming URLs from one format to another`. Members might have selected these tags for those reasons (e.g., `url-rewriting` for URL shortening), so they likely should remain separate tags.

Comment: I'm not convinced that there is a difference between changing the appearance of a URL and transforming a URL.

Comment: I was looking at this part of the wiki: `...from one format to another`, such as a file, whereas "appearance" might be associated with URL shortening or making it search engine friendly. It's probably a good idea to look at some of the posts tagged with these to see if there's any other differences. I'll do that and comment back.

Comment: I am seeing a preference for using the "url-rewriting" tag for search engine friendly related questions, and the "rewrite" tag for targeting files. Another thing I noticed is that if you type "rewrite" into the Tags, it doesn't display "url-rewriting" (because of the "-ing" ending). "Rewrite" is a commonly used expression so may be searched for explicitly, and hence no tag would be displayed if removed.

Comment: If rewrite were merged into url-rewriting then the system would make the suggestion for rewrite.  Test typing in "doubleclick" which I just merged into "google-dfp"

Comment: In that case, the merge might result in more specific choices between "mod-rewrite", "isapi-rewrite", and the catchall "url-rewriting", without the additional generic "rewrite". I'm good with it.

Comment: I performed the merge of rewrite -> url-rewriting

Answer (score 1):

I am going to agree with Stephen when he posted his answer, at first.

mod-rewrite (Mod_Rewrite?) is apart of the rewriting tag, but it also an actual name for an Apache Module. So are we referring to the Apache Module or not? This is the question for this.

Then URL-Rewrite is of making URLs fancier or changing them in general. So, I would keep it myself, and just remove the rewrite tag in general?

Comment: This question has already been marked as "status-completed" and "rewrite" is now a synonym for "url-rewriting". "mod-rewrite" is still its own tag and refers to the mod_rewrite Apache module (which naturally does include the topic of URL rewriting, as well as other things). Links to the appropriate tag wikis describing each of these tags is given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

These two are the same thing.

"rewrite" should be a synonym for "mod-rewrite"

Comment: They usually mean the same thing but rewrite can apply to iisrewrite, too.

Comment: Good point.  I withdraw my recommendation that these be merged.  I edited the [Tag:rewrite] tag wiki to reflect your thought.

Comment: And mod-rewrite can apply to more than just (url)rewriting.